# Imputation for an Entire Python/Pandas Dataframe with Yearly Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

> Dataframe 50 countries, 80 features (varying widely in scale), over 25 years.
>
> > The variance between feature values, and values per country within the same feature, is wide.

#### Trying to accurately impute the missing values across the whole dataframe, all at once.

Tried `SimpleImputer` with `Mean`, but this would give a mean for the entire feature column, and ignored any yearly time trend for that specific country.

- This led to the imputed values being wildly inaccurate for smaller countries, as their imputed values reflected the mean of that feature column across ALL the larger countries as well
- AND, if there was a trend for that feature declining across all countries, it would be ignored due to the mean being so much larger than the smaller countries'.

> ### TLDR;

## Currently:

```
       Year     x1     x2        x3   ... 
  
USA    1990     4      581000    472
USA    1991     5      723000    389
etc...

CHN    1990     5      482000    393
CHN    1991     7      623000    512
etc...

CDR    1990     1      NaN       97
CDR    1991     NaN    91000    NaN
etc...
```

***How can I impute the missing values most accurately and efficiently, where the imputation takes into account the scale of the country and feature, while noting the yearly time trend??***

## Goal:

```
       Year     x1     x2        x3   ... 
  
USA    1990     3      581000    472
USA    1991     5      723000    389
etc...

CHN    1990     5      482000    393
CHN    1991     7      623000    512
etc...

CDR    1990     1     (87000)    97
CDR    1991    (3)     91000    (95)
etc...
```

*Wherein the `3`, `87000`, and `95` would be suitable values as they follow a general time trend that other countries do, but the values are scaled to the other values in that same feature for the specific country (in this case CDR)*

- Using `SimpleImputer`, these values would be MUCH higher, and far less logical.

> - I know imputation is never perfect, but it can surely be made more accurate in this case
> - If there is a noticeable trend over the years for that country, how can I reflect that while keeping the imputed values to a scale that matches the feature for the particular country?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following techniques.

1. Random forest imputation .

   [you can refer to this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5796790/) .
2. Backward Forward filling(though it will just consider year) .
3. Log returns